# Is this a contraction mapping?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $T(x)=\frac{1}{20}e^{-x^2}\sin(wx)$ a contraction mapping? $w$ can be any real number.

Comment: Did you try computing $T'(x)$???

Comment: I did. It is hard to see whether or not the absolute value of derivative is less than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $w = 100$.  $T([-0.005,0]) = [-0.022{\dots}, 0]$.  So, no.  For this choice of $w$, the derivative exceeds $4$ on this interval, so this noncontractivity is entirely detectable by the usual method.

Answer (score 1):

$T'(0) = w/20$, so it's not a contraction if $|w| > 20$.  It does seem to be a contraction if $|w| \le 20$.